# Google maps is not displayed in IE 11

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I have the following markup with the problem mentioned above.
All works fine in FF and Chrome, but it doesn't work in all versions IE.
The Map is initialized but you can see only a gray rectangle instead. 
Full code is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDGCfF8PovjNXwEq42KcdIiIjPgNTNh5tI&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <style>
        .popup-window { position: absolute; z-index: 3000; top: 50%; left: 50%; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 10px; padding: 20px 30px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        .popup-window_map-search {width: 1200px; height: 616px; margin: -230px auto auto -600px; }
        .popup-window__content:after { content: " "; display: table; clear: both; }
        .popup-window__map-container { margin-top: 20px }
        .search_block {display: table-cell; width: 360px; padding-right:18px; vertical-align: top}
        .search-list__wrapper {border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-radius: 3px; margin-top: 10px; max-height: 417px; overflow: auto}
        .search-list li {padding: 6px 20px 7px; font-size: 14px; color: #404040; cursor: pointer; }
        .map_block {display: table-cell; width: 758px; border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-radius: 3px;}
    </style>

    <script>
        function init() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), { center: { lat: 78, lng: 22 }, zoom: 6 });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="site-body" onload="init()">
<div class="popup-window popup-window_map-search">
    <div class="popup-window__content">
        <div class="popup-window__map-container">
            <div class="search_block">

                <div class="search-list__wrapper">
                    <ul class="search-list">
                        <li>One</li>
                        <li>Two</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                        <li>6</li>
                        <li>7s</li>
                        <li>8</li>
                        <li>9</li>
                        <li>10</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="google-map" class="map_block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What versions of IE doesn't it work in?

Comment: i have tested it only in IE 11 and map is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to set a height to your map container (`.map-block`).
2. IE doesn't seem to like `display: table-cell;` for the positionning.

I was able to achieve the same design by setting both the `.map-block` and `.search-block` elements to `display: inline-table;` (and setting a height to the map element). Tested on IE10, works fine.